# Python-like dynamic argument unpacking in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a `std::map<int, std::vector<MyClass>>` and a function that accepts a dynamic number of iterators, specifically [`iter::zip_longest`](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools/blob/master/README.md#zip_longest).

I want to pass the vectors I have in the map to `zip_longest`, but given that there are a dynamic number of vectors in the map, I'm not seeing a straightforward way to achieve this. I know that it's doable with compile time constants using templates and `sizeof`, however I can't specify this at compile time.

What I essentially want to do is

```
std::vector<std::vector<MyClass>*> all_vectors;
for (const auto it : my_map) {
  all_vectors.push_back(&it.second);
}
for (const auto it : iter::zip_longest(*all_vectors)) {  // <-- Here using *all_vectors to unpack like in Python.
  // Do stuff here
}
```

Let me also say that I am aware that this can be achieved through other means than `zip_longest`, I'm just wondering if there is a clean way for me to use this existing function.

Comment: You can't.  The type and number of parameters a function takes are compile-time things.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I will be over here weeping.

Comment: you'll want an iterator based on a vector. should be reasonably easy to write. Dereferenceing it of course would need to yield a vector of references, which is not possible so you'd want to return either a vector of pointers or a vector of reference_wrappers

Comment: @RichardHodges I've got an existing solution that recreates the behavior provided by zip_longest. I was just wondering if I could use the existing well-tested function that we have instead of re implementing myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is a statically typed language. `zip_longest` is a function that produces a zip iterator based on the number of parameters that it gets. But the number of parameters a function gets is a *static* quantity in C++. If you need to give a function a runtime number of values, then you have to provide a runtime range or container or something of that sort. And `zip_longest` isn't built for that.

Answer (score 2):

The static type system of C++ is static.  You have a dynamic number of elements in that vector.  So you cannot have the static type system of C++ process the result, barring some fancy "generate all static types up to N then dispatch to it" that is reasonably inefficient and not all that wealdly.

`zip_longest` is *not* a function.  It is a function template.  A function template generates a function, often at the call site, by statically examining its arguments.

Now, it would be quite possible to create an iterator that, given a dynamic vector of containers, returns a dynamic vector of elements.  The dynamic information in the source argument -- the number of elements -- corresponds to the dynamic elements in the type returned.

So something like this is possible:

```
std::vector<std::vector<MyClass>*> all_vectors;
for (const auto it : my_map) {
  all_vectors.push_back(&it.second);
}
for (const auto& elems : vec_zip_longest(all_vectors)) {
  // elems is a vector of boost::optional<std::ref<MyClass*>>
  // Do stuff here
}
```

doing this for the restricted case of just for(:) loops would look something like:

```
template<class C>
struct vec_zip_longest {
  using elem_iterator = decltype( std::begin( std::declval<C&>() ) );
  using elem = std::decay_t< decltype( *std::declval<elem_iterator&>() ) >;
  std::vector< std::optional<elem_iterator> > current;
  std::vector< elem_iterator > finish;

    vec_zip_longest( std::vector<C>& vec ) {
        for (auto&& c : vec )
        {
            current.emplace_back( std::begin(c) );
            finish.emplace_back( std::end(c) );
            if (current.back() == finish.back())
                current.back() = {};
        }
    }

  bool advance() {
    bool retval = false;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < current.size(); ++i) {
      auto& it = current[i];
      //std::cerr << "advancing\n";
      if (!it)
      {
        //std::cerr << "already done\n";
        continue;
      }
      ++*it;
      if (*it == finish[i]) {
        //std::cerr << "reached end\n";
        it = std::nullopt;
        continue;
      }
      //std::cerr << "advanced\n";
      retval = true;
    }
    return retval;
  }
  struct iterator {
    vec_zip_longest* parent = nullptr;
    friend bool operator==(iterator const& lhs, iterator const& rhs) {
      return lhs.parent == rhs.parent;
    }
    friend bool operator!=(iterator const& lhs, iterator const& rhs) {
      return lhs.parent != rhs.parent;
    }
    void operator++()& {
      if(!parent->advance())
        parent = nullptr;
    }
    auto operator*() {
      std::vector<std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<elem>>> retval;
      retval.reserve(parent->current.size());
      for(auto&& oit:parent->current) {
        //std::cerr << "getting element\n";
        if (oit) {
          //std::cerr << "something there\n";
          retval.emplace_back(**oit);
        } else {
          //std::cerr << "nothing there\n";
          retval.emplace_back();
        }
      }
      return retval;
    }
  };
  iterator begin() {
    return {this};
  }
  iterator end() {
    return {};
  }
};
template<class C>
vec_zip_longest(std::vector<C>&)->vec_zip_longest<C>;
```

in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5244e4a309e37a45).

A "more proper" iterator would take a bit more boilerplate, and you could not technically make it stronger than an input iterator.  Also having support for non-member `begin`/`end` takes more work which I skipped here.

Test code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo{ {1,2,3}, {4,5}, {6} };
vec_zip_longest zip { foo };
for (auto&& c:zip)
{
    for (auto&& e : c ) {
        if (e)
            std::cout << *e << ",";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

output is:

> ```
> 1,4,6,
> 2,5,
> 3,
> ```